# mySQL Function to make address string

Tags: mysql, function

I want to have a mySQL function that returns a string which is based on input parameters. So I have no blanks.

I tried the following but it tells me there is a syntax error at the beginning but I cannot see it.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `NewProc`(`add1` varchar,`add2` varchar,`add3` varchar,`town` varchar,`USState` varchar,`pcode` varchar,`country` varchar)
    RETURNS varchar(250)

    BEGIN
    DECLARE fulladdress VARCHAR;

    fulladdress = add1;
    if (add2 <>'')
        {fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',add2);}
    if (add3 <> '')
        {fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',add3);}
    fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',town);
    if (USState <> '')
        {fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',USState);}
    if (pcode <> '')
        {fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress', ',pcode;}
    fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',country)};

    RETURN fulladdress;
    END;
```

Comment: lot of issues , `varchar` needs a length something as `varchar(100)` and also `{fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',add2);}` why curly braces ?

Comment: I was using a wizard that did not ask for a length of input parameters. So much for that wizard so I have added the length and the error has moved on to something in:

    fulladdress = add1;
 if (add2 is not blank)
  fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',add2);

Comment: remove all the curly braces.

Comment: I have done that but it is will telling me there is a still an error somewhere on these lines:

fulladdress = add1;
 if (add2 <> '') 
  fulladdress = CONCAT(fulladdress,', ',add2);

Comment: @user3613255 Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `concat_ws` function instead, then you would only have to specify the separator once, and it ignores null parameter values. Note that you'll have to adjust the size of the varchar parameters to fit your needs. Something like this should give the desired result:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
FUNCTION `NewProc`(
    add1 varchar(20),
    add2 varchar(20),
    add3 varchar(20),
    town varchar(20),
    USState varchar(20),
    pcode varchar(20),
    country varchar(20)
)
    RETURNS varchar(250)

    BEGIN
    DECLARE fulladdress VARCHAR(250);

    if (add2 = '') then set add2 = null; end if; 
    if (add3 = '') then set add3 = null; end if;
    if (town = '') then set town = null; end if;
    if (USState = '') then set USState = null; end if;
    if (pcode = '') then set pcode = null; end if;


    RETURN concat_ws(', ', add1, add2, add3, town, USState, pcode, country);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The function can probably be written in a smarter way, but my knowledge of MySQL is rather limited...